# Linq on List<object>

Tags: c#, linq, listobject

Existing legacy code is as follows:

```
List<object> myItems;
//myItems gets populated by a method call

foreach (object[] item in myItems)
{
  string Id = item[0].ToString();
  string Number = item[1].ToString();

  //now do some processing if Number satisfies some criteria
}
```

would like to convert this using linq to select all `Id`s that match a certain `Number`.

All suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use object...

Comment: Afraid that is not our call. That is how we're getting data...

Answer (score 3):

Use `Select()` and `Where()`

```
bool IsSatisfyingNumber(String number) {
    // True if number satisfies some criteria
}

List<String> matchingIds = myItems
    .Where(item => IsSatisfyingNumber(item[1].ToString()))
    .Select(item => item[0].ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The list `myItems` contains items of type `object` where each this item is actually `object[]` so we need to cast to `object[]` first and then filter and select based on the searched `certain number`.

```
string certainNumber = "1";
var myIds = myItems
    .Where(o => ((object[]) o)[1].ToString() == certainNumber)
    .Select(o => ((object[]) o)[0].ToString());
```

The [equality operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx) on strings performs `an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison` so change it in the `Where...` if you need some different kind of comparison in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working and wanted to share the information:

```
var myIds = 
(from item in myItems.Cast<object[]>()
  select new
  { Id = item[0], Number = (string)item[1] }
)
.Where(x => x.Number == filtercondition)
.Select(x => (string)x.Id)
.ToList();
```